# All div overflow:auto scrollbars are hidden in some Chrome browsers for ExtJS 5.1.0 apps

Tags: google-chrome, scrollbar, overflow, extjs5, amazon-workspaces

### General Problem

We've had a long-standing problem with our two ExtJS 5.1.0 apps that div scrollbars don't show in Chrome, using only our QA testers' AWS Workspace Chrome browsers. They don't see this in other websites using that Chrome, only our two applications. We've been able to ignore this since the problem was isolated, but now a user is having the same problem.

We've been able to confirm that the difference is that wherever there's a div that *should be* overflow: auto is being generated as overflow: hidden. So scrollbars for grids, dropdowns, etc don't render but the div can still be scrolled via other means (tabbing, page down).

I've been looking for general ideas about what could cause this--is it ExtJS? Windows setting? Chrome setting? Again, the problem is isolated to AWS Workspace's Chrome and a user's Chrome.

### Versions

Chrome:
AWS Workspace has exact same Chrome version as me, 79.0.3945.88.
User has Chrome 80.0.3987.149 (up-to-date).

Windows:
AWS Workspace is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.
User has Windows 10.

### What We've Tried

These are all troubleshooting steps we've tried in the AWS Workspace Chrome:

1. Disabled all extensions. Also ran in incognito mode which should do this also. The extensions are nothing that I don't also have, and I don't see the problem.
2. Inspected Chrome's flags--they're all default, and again not different than what I have.
3. Disabled Chrome's “Use hardware acceleration when available” setting and restarted Chrome.
4. Previously opened a ticket up with AWS and they were unable to help.
5. Researched any connection of this to Chrome, ExtJS, or Windows Server 2016 Datacenter without luck. Only found general information about "what to do if you have scrolling problems in Chrome".

### Other Problems Our Apps Have in AWS Workspace Chrome

Listing these in case it helps trigger any ideas about the underlying problem, but focusing on the scrolling for now. Again these are isolated to Chrome in AWS Workspace (unclear if the user is seeing these also):

1. Drag and drop doesn't work.
2. Tabs that aren't the selected tab when the tab bar is loaded don't load at all.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was related to touchscreens. Our user has a touchscreen laptop (and didn't realize it for a while, we asked about this early on). And the Amazon Workspaces are touchscreen-compatible, as they have a "HID compliant touch screen" device listed in Device Manager > Human Interface Devices. So something about touchscreens + Chrome/Edge is telling ExtJS 5.1.0 that the device is mobile and scrollbars shouldn't be rendered.

Solutions:

- For our user, she was happy to disable her touchscreen device and this worked for her.
- For Amazon Workspaces, disabling the touchscreen device did not work. For Chrome we were able to resolve by adding `--touch-events=enabled` to the Chrome shortcut. There are various touch-related Chrome flags mentioned online as a solution, but none of those are available in the current version. Anything touch-related we did find in Chrome's list of flags didn't help.
- I haven't looked for a solution for Edge if someone uses Edge and wants to keep their touchscreen. This is fine for us right now. (Because we realized Edge has the problem also, presumably due to Chromium. Did not see it with Firefox.)
- And I did confirm using ExtJs' Kitchen Sink examples that I can replicate the problem in 5.1.0 with both a touchscreen laptop and an Amazon Workspace. Also that I can't replicate the problem in the current version, so we should be good once we upgrade.